# Limiting the Q size on Java's 1.7 ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

We're doing some tasks that require external I/O, and are recursive.  To accomplish this, we're prototyping switching from the old ExecutorService to the ForkJoinPool.  Our degree of parallelism will obviously be higher than our number of cores, since we'll spend most of our thread's time in I/O wait.  We only have synchronous network API's so we don't have any other options here.

In the old ExecutorService, you could reject tasks so that they don't pile up by setting the queue size.  In the ForkJoinPool, this doesn't seem possible, and it seems it expands to this value in the Oracle 1.7 implementation.

```
/**
 * Maximum size for submission queue array. Must be a power of two
 * less than or equal to 1 << (31 - width of array entry) to
 * ensure lack of index wraparound, but is capped at a lower
 * value to help users trap runaway computations.
 */
private static final int MAXIMUM_QUEUE_CAPACITY = 1 << 24; // 16M
```

This is a significantly larger queue that we want.  Is there a fork/join pool implementation with the following features?

1) The ability to provide a facility to name threads as they're created?  We have a couple of I/O worker pools, and it's useful for debugging to see which pool created and owns the thread.

2) Provide the ability to set the max queue size.  We actually want it to be 0 when scheduling the parent tasks.  If there is no capacity in the scheduler and the parent task is started, we want it to run in the thread calling submit and attempting to schedule.  This will give us an auto throttle mechanism by slowing the caller down.

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use the third constructor:

   ForkJoinPool(int parallelism, ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler, boolean asyncMode)
2. No. But the nice thing about open-source software is that you can create your own copy and modify it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding your first query:*

You can implement [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) as below

```
class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   String name;

   public SimpleThreadFactory (String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r,name);
   }
 }
```

And you can pass this Factory in ForkJoinPool constructor

```
ForkJoinPool(int parallelism,
            ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory,
            Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler,
            boolean asyncMode)
```

*Regarding your second query:*

`ForkJoinPool` does not provide flexibility to control worker queue size.